# How to setup wine for networking in linux

Tags: networking, fedora, wine

How to setup wine for networking?

Unless i have linux access to my windows network, i can't do wine discover the windows network. How to do it?, also wine hasnt cmd line utility so i can't use commands like `net use`, `ping` etc this is the question too.

Answer (score 3):

You can't: Wine only accesses the networking functionality from Linux.

You should mount your Windows shares using `mount`, then instruct Wine (using `winecfg`) to assign a drive letter for them.

The `ping` command is part of standard Linux install.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I will try clear more the matter. My linux can see win network ping mount and so on. Question is to ping and use network command from wine. I wonder why wine internet browser avant can access the net (external in his case) and the other part of wine stuff not.

Comment: Try this: http://wiki.winehq.org/FAQ#head-f000601e2d4ad173587b19c8d2f097d6dfba8cbe . If network only works in some apps, but not in others, you might have found a bug in Wine.

Answer (score 2):

Just pointing: Wine has builtin cmd utility, however it is not fully functional. To run it, simply type

```
wine cmd
```

Answer (score 0):

I never tried, but copy these binaries you need from your Windows installation to `~/.wine/drive_c/windows/` should work

But on the other hand, why wouldn't you try to find a replacement that runs natively in Linux?